# What is the name of the profession that makes RTOW charts?

Tags: aircraft-performance

What is the name of the profession an aerodrome operator would need if they wanted to make an aerodrome RTOW (Regulatory Takeoff Weight) chart for a specific aircraft?

I've researched and found some companies who developed a takeoff chart specifically for a Falcon 10 at Canberra in the past but haven't been able to identify the name of the profession who actually build the charts. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "name of the profession" seems like an XY problem. Is the real question "How can I get an RTOW chart for my aerodrome?"?

Comment: I bet the answer will ve along the lines of the answer to the question about "who uses the chainsaw in an infantry platoon?" Quite surprisingly the answer is "whoever can".

Comment: It's probably a type of aerospace engineer, or aeronautics engineer...

Answer (score 5):

It's usually rather the aircraft operator or their contractor who calculates these charts, rather than the aerodrome operator. This is due to some of the required input data only known to the aircraft operator (e.g. aircraft/engine configuration, performance relevant standard procedures like V1 policy or minimum turn height etc.). The profession is most commonly referred to as Aircraft Performance Engineer, sometimes just Performance Engineer, or more generally Flight Operations Engineer.

Unfortunately I can't find decent public sources to back my (very substantiated but unproven...) claim other than loads of job offers, I'm afraid.